# Multi-Column layout messing up in Chrome when trying to animate

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, css, multiple-columns

I'm using jQuery to animate a multi-column layout that runs off the screen horizontally. I have two controllers to move back and fourth (one red one blue). The animation seems to work fine in Firefox and Safari but when I've tested it in Chrome the text duplicates across the screen and just generally messes up in a weird way.

Here's the link to the example: http://jsfiddle.net/darcyclarke/q8etQ/11/
Here's a screen shot of what happens in my version of Chrome for reference: http://cl.ly/3m2d012L0n303n1a1P2L

Wondering if anyone has any idea why this seems to happen and if there is a way to fix it. Appreciate all feedback.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everyone is too slow to answer my question, and no one seems to have any knowledge on the subject I've gone ahead and queried good ol' Paul Irish (http://paulirish.com) who is on the Google Chrome Developer Tools team. He let me know that the bug seems to have been fixed in version 12.x of Chrome. Obviously, that's 6 weeks away form a stable release but it's good to know if anyone else runs into the same issue.